# Loading and 404 error in allure reports for in different browsers (Chrome, IE, Edge)

Tags: python-3.x, allure, python-behave

My end goal is to create html report for the test runs done in behave(python) framewwork.

I got the json using this command:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure_result_folder ./features
```

It created few json files allure_result_folder. Subsequently I used this command to generate the allure_result files:

```
allure generate allure_result_folder
```

The above command generated allure-report folder. So far so good. Now when I try to open the index.html in any browser (tried with Edge, IE, Chrome) I get the following page:

[image]

Below is the screenshot of allure/data folder:

[image]

Not really sure what is going on. Any help is appreciated.
Even a different library that can create the html report from behave runs will also help.

Comment: Want to add, rest all other tabs in the report is showing 404.

Comment: `allure open allure_result_folder` should open this report in your web browser

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to open the report in any browser is to run allure serve which creates a server and opens the report in your default browser. It can't be opened directly from the index.html file because of default Webkit security settings which forbids Ajax requests on the local filesystem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This seem to be a comment but not an answer. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)